# can't use pointer to find right element - poiting on object is null on return from function

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote some code with some function that get pointer and some const and need to return the element that its point on  =

I can't find the reason that my pointer is null on return from the function - 
any help please

```
    class MyClass 
    {
        // Some Code    
    }

    void FindCurrectMyClass(const int val, MyClass* myClassPtr)
    {
        switch(val)
        {
            case(0):
            {
                myClassPtr = &myClass0;
            }
            break;

            case(1):
            {
                myClassPtr = &myClass1;     // get here and myClassPtr is not null
            }
            break;

            case(2):
            {
                myClassPtr = &myClass2;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    void main()
    {
        MyClass myClass0;
        MyClass myClass1;
        MyClass myClass2;   

        MyClass* myClassPtr = nullPtr;

        FindCurrectMyClass(1, myClassPtr );

        myClassPtr->Func();     // myClassPtr is null 
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, try to put together a working example. Besides, you are passing the pointer by value, and the assignments `myClassPtr = &myClass` mutate the copy in the function scope, not the one in `main`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because there is no declaration for `myClass0` visible to `FindCurrectMyClass`. My guess would be that you've defined your variables twice, once globally and once inside `main`. That would explain why the pointers aren't what you expect them to be.

Comment: the code compile - and the value is on .. 3 instance of myClass .. no <n>

Comment: @Yanshof I'm sure **your** code compiles but the code you have posted does not. We often have this problem, people post part of their code and miss out vital pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit, I imagined we are in C, but we are in C++**

replace

```
void FindCurrectMyClass(const int val, MyClass* myClassPtr)
```

by

```
void FindCurrectMyClass(const int val, MyClass*& myClassPtr)
```

else you only modify the local parameter so when you go back nothing is done and *myClassPtr* is still null

---

Of course you have to put

```
MyClass myClass0;
MyClass myClass1;
MyClass myClass2;
```

for instance at global scope before *FindCurrectMyClass* else that one cannot access them

Comment: Surely better to return the pointer rather than set via a parameter.

Comment: @john sure; but I just fixe the problem without doing more change in the philosophy, to indicate to the O.P. how to use an output parameter

Comment: this not solve me anything because i don't want to use  pointer  to pointer  - and one pointer is need to be ok

Comment: @Yanshof you are copying in the pointer, you can't change the outside pointer if you don't pass it as either `MyClass*&` or `MyClass**`

Comment: @Yanshof that solve your problem. I think you just you do not understand the difference between a pointer and an object. If you want something more simple as john says do not use an output parameter but return the address

Comment: @Yanshof  ah yes we are in C++, I supposed we are in C, I edited my answer

Comment: Can someone explain why 

void FindCurrectMyClass(const int val, MyClass* myClassPtr)
 does not work and 


void FindCurrectMyClass(const int val, MyClass*& myClassPtr)
   is working ?? ??

Comment: @Yanshof This was explained multiple times for you, in the comments. But, if that's not enough, you can read about [the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).